# Kivy TypeError unsupported operand type

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

I'm getting a TypeError when trying to use operands in my kivy code

```
 TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'ObservableReferenceList' and 'int'
```

I've read that it's to do with instantiating the NumericProperty class in the python code but I'm not sure what variable I've got to set it to, size?

```
<DonationType>:
    name: "donation type"
        RoundedButton:
            size_hint: 0.417, 0.15625
            pos_hint: {"x": 0.5282, "y": 0.55}
            Image:
                source: 'House.PNG'
                size: self.parent.size / 2
                pos: self.parent.pos
                stretch: True
                keep_ratio: False
```

The error is in the self.parent.size / 2 part of the code. The Rounded button is a modified Button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `size` property is an ObservableReferenceList that does not support division, what you should do in this case is to apply it to each section:

```
size: .5 * self.parent.width, .5 * self.parent.height
```